# Using vbscript regular expression to conditional replace dates

Tags: regex, vbscript

I would like to use regex to replace the actual dates in the string to YYYYMMDD. However, my string might contain 2 types of dates, it could either be 20160531 or 160531. For these two, I have to replace them with YYYYMMDD and YYMMDD. So the followings are two examples:

Employment_salary_20160531 -> Employment_salary_YYYYMMDD

Employment_salary_160531 -> Employment_salary_YYMMDD

Wondering if it is possible to do this within a single regex without using an IFELSE statement?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will provide you with accurate validation of the date that's entered. The other regex will work but it's dirty. It will accept 5000 as year.

The short answer: ((19|20)\d{2}|[0-9]{2})(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([012][0-9]|3[0-1])

The Long but thoroughly tested answer...

```
stringtest1 = "Employment_salary_20160531"
stringtest2 = "Employment_salary_990212"
stringtest3 = "Employment_salary_990242"
wscript.echo : wscript.echo "---------------------------------------------------" : wscript.echo 
wscript.echo "Trying: " & stringtest1 & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & vbtab & " => " & sanitizedate(stringtest1)
wscript.echo : wscript.echo "---------------------------------------------------" : wscript.echo 
wscript.echo "Trying: " & stringtest2 & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & vbtab & " => " & sanitizedate(stringtest2)
wscript.echo : wscript.echo "---------------------------------------------------" : wscript.echo 
wscript.echo "Trying: " & stringtest3 & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & vbtab & " => " & sanitizedate(stringtest3)
wscript.echo : wscript.echo "---------------------------------------------------" : wscript.echo 

Function sanitizedate(str)
    Set objRE = New RegExp
    objRE.Pattern    = "((19|20)\d{2}|[0-9]{2})(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([012][0-9]|3[0-1])"
    objRE.IgnoreCase = True
    objRE.Global     = False
    objRE.Multiline  = true
    Set objMatch = objRE.Execute(str)
    If objMatch.Count = 1 Then
        Select Case Len(objMatch.Item(0))
            Case "8"
                sanitizedate = Replace(str, objMatch.Item(0), "YYYYMMDD")
            Case "6"
                sanitizedate = Replace(str, objMatch.Item(0), "YYMMDD")
        End Select
    Else
        sanitizedate = str
    End if
End Function
```

### Validation Results

---

Trying: Employment_salary_20160531

```
     => Employment_salary_YYYYMMDD
```

---

Trying: Employment_salary_990212

```
     => Employment_salary_YYMMDD
```

---

Trying: Employment_salary_990242 **failed because 42 is not a valid date**

```
     => Employment_salary_990242
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get you right. But seems  there is two different replacement `YYYYMMDD` and `YYMMDD` which doing that is impossible by just one single pattern.

You can match those two separated pattern by this:

```
/(^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$)|(^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$)/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nH3lE0/4)

As you see, pattern above matches both `20160531` and `160531`. But you cannot replace them with both `YYYYMMDD` *(for `20160531`)* and `YYMMDD` (for `160531`). You actually can replace them with either `YYYYMMDD` or `YYMMDD`.

Otherwise you need two separated patterns if you want two separated replacements:

```
/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/
/* and replace with `YYYYMMDD` */

/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/
/* and replace with YYMMDD */
```